# Clipping images using GDAL

Tags: gdal, clip

I would like to clip some tiff files using cutline from kml file.

[image]

```
.\gdalwarp.exe -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -cutline boundingbox.kml source.tif result.tif
```

It works quite well but as a result I have files with the same size as before.

Is it possible to adjust result image size to the result content?

Here I would like to get rid of that black border.

[image]

Edit:
When I add -crop_to_cutline parameter then result is even worse:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you've define you cutline you have to tell it to crop the image to the cutline like so:

```
gdal.Warp(Outraster, Inraster, format = 'GTiff', cutlineDSName = polygon, cropToCutline = True
```

Comment: Well the result is even worse because output image has size of full clipper. Please take a look at my question which I edited.

Comment: I believe if you define an Alpha band for your raster you should be good using 
-dstalpha:

Comment: Yes it looks better but size is the same, I thought that maybe size (dimensions) can be reduced as well to fit only area with image (that small corner) :)

Comment: maybe define -srcalpha aswell...

Comment: if that doesn't work you could clip your "clipper" polygon to the extent of your raster file prior to doing this clip